# Ni que vs ni siquiera

Tags: gramática

> Purificación se comió tres filletes. - Ni que estuviese muerta de hambre.

Me gustaría saber si es similar a la expresión

> Purificación se comió tres filletes. - Ni siquiera estaba muerta de hambre.

¡Gracias!

Answer (score 2):

Las oraciones:

1) Ni que estuviese (=estuviera) muerta de hambre.

y

2) Ni siquiera estaba muerta de hambre.

son parecidas pero no idénticas.

Se parecen en que, en ambos casos, se asegura que Purificación no tenía hambre.

Difieren en la modalidad. Mientras que (2) sólo es una aseveración, (1) conlleva una crítica irónica, o un tono burlón, que sólo podría expresarse a través de (2) mediante una exclamación: ¡Ni siquiera estaba muerta de hambre!

Otro ejemplo en el presente:

A. Necesito vacaciones.

B. Ni que fueras un gran trabajador. (Sólo si fueras un gran trabajador merecerías vacaciones.)

B'. Pero si ni siquiera trabajas. (Una mera declaración: No trabajas.)

Comment: Bravo.  Qué buena explicación.  Quería agregar, no sé si lo ves así también: El (1) tiene un tono cínico y burlón; el (2) tiene un tono de reproche e indignación.

Answer (score -1):

Ni que: usalo como una suposicion de algo, como si ya lo hubieras echo.
Ni que hubiera lavado mi carro.

El carro puede estar limpio y dirias, Ni que hubiera lavado mi carro. porque parece que ya lo esta.

Quieres decir que parece que ya esta lavado, en el caso de que estuviera lavado.

ni siquiera:
algo que no has podido hacer
ni siquiera he lavado mi carro.
Todavia no.

Comment: Astrid, recomiendo que cuides la ortografía y los acentos.  Recomiendo que instales una extensión a tu browser para chequear automáticamente.  Y mira que puedes usar negritas, por ej.: **Ni que**: úsalo como un a suposición de algo, como si ya lo hubieras hecho. *Ni que hubiera lavado mi carro*. (etc.) Puedes editar tu respuesta, oprimiendo donde dice "edit" (entre "share" y "flag").